# Grails 5 how to get next sequence id

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

For a form I need as a default the next sequence id in the form. Do you guys have any idea's how to tackle this with hibernate?

```
id column: 'KEY', sqlType: 'NUMBER', generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'Test.test_SEQ'], length: 10
```

I tried to make a new object and get the id but this turns in a null.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.